# Use paste.deploy to serve a twisted application

Tags: python, twisted, wsgi

I'm working on a project that has two parts:

1. A WSGI-enabled web app written with pylons and served with `python-paste`
2. A python-twisted application that has nothing to do with `HTTP` or `WSGI`.

I'd like to keep the configuration for both apps in the same configuration file. I'd also like to use `paste serve` to launch both the `WSGI` server and the twisted server.

Is this possible? Can I configure `paste` to understand twisted `.tac` files?

Comment: it certainly works in the other direction i.e., serve a wsgi application using `twistd` e.g., django https://github.com/robgolding63/backtrac/blob/master/twisted/plugins/backtracweb_plugin.py

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely unlikely that trying to do this is going to be worth the effort.  `paster serve` has it's own event loop, threadpool, etc. and Twisted apps expect something quite different.

You could try writing your own `paster` subcommand, but you're probably better off writing a `.tac` file that serves both apps for use with `twistd`.